# Creating Java Project on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm a beginner to Java. I have installed eclipse,jre and jdk. Eclipse is not showing the option to create a Java project, probably because it is not finding Java on my computer. I have even set the environment variable path to the bin folder. What am I doing wrong? Below is the screen shot of my eclipse(luna) window. My PC runs on Windows 8.1 64 bit.

[image: Screenshot of the eclipse window]

Comment: Which eclipse did you download?

Comment: Are you eclipse latest version? Download eclipse latest version and try it..

Comment: Use the below link to download http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/indigo/SR2/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32-x86_64.zip&mirror_id=1136

Comment: @BackSlash I think I have downloaded Eclipse for C/C++. Could that be the reason it is not running Java? I figured it could run Java.

Comment: Is your c/c++ perspective working?

Comment: If I re-install Eclipse can I have it running Java, C++ and PyDev simultaneously?

Comment: @NikhilEm It definitely is. You need to download [Eclipse for Java Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/lunasr1)

Comment: Try downloading Eclipse IDE for JAVA Developers from here https://spring.io/tools/eclipse

Comment: @NikhilEm Or just open the eclipse marketplace and install the Java Developement Tools